# How to remove a relative shift when plotting with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this data that I am trying to plot using pandas:

```
df['SGP_sum'].iloc[0:16] = 
Date
2018-01-01 00:00:00     99.998765
2018-01-01 01:00:00     99.993401
2018-01-01 02:00:00    100.005571
2018-01-01 03:00:00    100.027737
2018-01-01 04:00:00    100.022474
2018-01-01 05:00:00    100.039800
2018-01-01 06:00:00    100.043310
2018-01-01 07:00:00    100.045207
2018-01-01 08:00:00    100.045201
2018-01-01 09:00:00    100.043810
2018-01-01 10:00:00    100.042977
2018-01-01 11:00:00    100.054589
2018-01-01 12:00:00    100.052009
2018-01-01 13:00:00    100.040163
2018-01-01 14:00:00    100.009129
2018-01-01 15:00:00     99.975595
Name: SGP_sum, dtype: float64
```

But when I plot it, this is what I see: ( I get negative values in the display)

```
df['SGP_sum'].iloc[0:16].plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is treating your values less than 100 as negative values due to the scale of your y axis being +1e2.

Try plotting without this scaling on the axis.